# Unexpected string literal when I'm trying to load the result of the query on a table (bq load)

Tags: shell, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the bq command line to load the result of a query on a table and then running another query to append the result on the same table. Basically what I'm trying to do is remove duplicates from a incremental table. But I'm getting an error when I try to execute the script.

`Syntax error: Unexpected string literal "select r.* from test_table.reservations r where id ..." at [1:1]`

The part of the script where I'm facing the error:

```
query_wo_inc="select r.* 
from test_table.reservations r
where id NOT IN (select id from inc_table.reservations);"

test_query_wo_inc=\"$(echo $query_wo_inc)\"
echo $query_wo_inc

bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table='staging_test_table.'reservations $test_query_wo_inc

# load the incremental data on the staging table
query_inc="select r.* from inc_table.reservations r"
test_query_inc=\"$(echo $query_inc)\"
echo $query_inc

bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --append_table=true --destination_table='staging_test_table.'reservations $test_query_inc
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
echo "could not create the staging table"
exit 
fi
# re-create the full table
bq rm -f -t test_table.reservations
bq cp staging_test_table.reservations test_table.reservations
bq rm -f -t inc_table.reservations
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimal example with similar error message:

```
query="select * from (select 1)"
bq query $query
```

Fixed:

```
query="select * from (select 1)"
bq query "$query"
```

The trick:

> Add quotes (" ") around your query variable.